# Why would the Visual C# 2008 Compiler think one explicitly declared and referenced type is another unreferenced one?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, types, declaration

I have the following code:

```
namespace FVProductions.Base
{
    public struct Color
    {
        public byte B, G, R, A;

        public Color(float r, float g, float b, float a)
        {
            R = (byte)(Math.Min(1.0f, Math.Max(0.0f, r)) * 255);
            G = (byte)(Math.Min(1.0f, Math.Max(0.0f, g)) * 255);
            B = (byte)(Math.Min(1.0f, Math.Max(0.0f, b)) * 255);
            A = (byte)(Math.Min(1.0f, Math.Max(0.0f, a)) * 255);
        }

        public Color(Vector3 rgb)
            :this(rgb.X,rgb.Y,rgb.Z,1)
        {
        }
    }
}

namespace FVProductions.Base.Graphics
{
    public class ShaderParameter<T>
    {
        private T Value;
        public T GetValue() { return Value; }
    }
}

namespace FVProductions.NewGame
{
    public class TerrainShader : Shader, IFullTextured, IStandardLit
    {
        private ShaderParameter<Vector3> epAmbient;

        public FVProductions.Base.Color AmbientColor
        {
            get { return new FVProductions.Base.Color(epAmbient.GetValue()); }
            set { epAmbient.SetValue(value.ToVector3()); }
        }
    }
}
```

The type, FVProductions.Base.Color is in a referenced library.  epAmbient.GetValue returns a Vector3 and FVProductions.Base.Color has a constructor with a single Vector3 parameter.  The project does not reference System.Drawing.  However, the compiler is generating the following error:

> error CS0012: The type 'System.Drawing.Color' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

That's on the TerrainShader.AmbientColor get{} line, at the return keyword.  Why would the compiler ever assume an explicitly declared type is another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  FVProductions.Base.Color is a base class in a base library and has a constructor that accepts a System.Drawing.Color.  The project that has the problem code does not reference System.Drawing.  When using the Color class, it was having trouble linking the System.Drawing.Color constructor even though it wasn't used.  So, I discovered two solutions:

Have the upper library reference the System.Drawing library even though it won't be used.

Remove the System.Drawing.Color constructor from FVProductions.Base.Color.

Either will allow the project to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely  epAmbient.GetValue returns 'System.Drawing.Color', not FVProductions.Base.Color as you think.

Comment: epAmbient.GetValue returns a Vector3.  FVProductions.Base.Color has a constructor that accepts a single Vector3 parameter.  Sorry I was unclear.

Comment: And what type of epAmbient is? Consider posting sample that reproduces the error or at least looks semi-complete with all related classes and namespcase...

Comment: epAmbient is a ShaderParameter<Vector3>.  I'd have to post *a lot* of code for it to be in context.  Let me see what I can do.

Comment: Try to first directly replace epAmbient.GetValue with new Vector3(). I bet it'll compile ok.

Comment: Nope, replacing with "new Vector3()" has the same compiler error.

Comment: Looks ok to me and semi-reasonably compiles. No ideas. I'd rename Color class to something else temporary to see if error persists - at least you;ll be able to narrow it down. Good luck.

Comment: Now this is weird... I changed the name to FvColor, rebooted my computer, rebuilt the solution, and it still had that error on that line.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another version of .NET installed on your system, you may be referencing the wrong version. Make sure any references in your .config file match the 2.0 version, and also make sure there are no stray .dlls copied to your bin folder.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Just checked the System references and they're all the same runtime version.  I don't have a .config file that I know of, though.  I'm using Xna 3.1.  There are no extra DLLs in the output folder either.